# How do I read formdata in node js server when its a buffer

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer

I've created a formData which contains a JSON file and image/video file. And send a post method to the server. After the POST method, server console.log a req.body and the output is a buffer type. I want to convert this buffer to original data, JSON and file, but I have no clue of doing it.

```
var returnValue = new FormData();
var file = $('#video')[0].files[0];

const results = {
     ...
}

returnValue.append('DATA', JSON.stringify(results))
returnValue.append('FILE', file);

const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    body: returnValue
}

const request = await fetch('url', options)
.then(function(response){
    const responseJson = response.json()
    .then(function(output){
        console.log(output)
    })
})
```

```
<Buffer 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 57 65 62 4b 69 74 46 6f 72 6d 42 6f 75 6e 64 61 72 79 6c 4a 63 49 6e 55 7a 51 47 37 45 44 42 5a 6a 54 0d 0a 43 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 2d ... 3572699 more bytes>
```

Answer (score 0):

This converts the contents of the buffer to utf8:

```
console.log(output.toString('utf8'));
```

Choose another encoding if utf8 doesn't fit your actual data.

Comment: I've manage to console.log as a sting(Thanks to you) but the file too. I only need 'DATA' from formdata, how do I detach DATA and FILE??